# ORACLE SQL: Group the data by the last 4 weeks

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a trouble with dates, i need to do a query that count the ids from the last four weeks.

I tried this, but it doesn't works.

```
SELECT count(a.id), sysdate
FROM table_1 a, table_2 b
WHERE b.fk_id = a.id
AND a.column = some_id
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=4
```

I need a output like this

```
| count(a.id) | week |
|      2      |   1  |
|      6      |   2  |
|      7      |   3  |
|      21     |   4  |
```

So, the " count(a.id) " values are the count of the ID's in one of the past 4 weeks.

Comment: Can you please add your table's DDL? For example, by using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Can you give your sample input data along with the expected output? From your question description I can't figure why this would need to be recursive.

Comment: Clearly you have to have some kind of date or week-number field in one of your tables, or else there's no way to know which week your rows go with. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and provide us with additional information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a MS SQL Server solution.  You should be able to convert it to Oracle if needed.

```
select count(id) as 'count(a.id)'
, datepart(week, MyDate) as 'week'

from table_1

where datepart(week, MyDate) between datepart(week, getdate()) - 5 and datepart(week, getdate()) - 1

group by datepart(week, MyDate)
```

And here's my attempt at doing this in Oracle.

```
select count(a.id)
, Week

from (
  select cast(TO_CHAR(MyDate, 'WW') as int) + 
    case when cast(TO_CHAR(MyDate, 'D') as int) < cast(TO_CHAR(trunc(MyDate, 'year'), 'D') as int) then 1 else 0 end  Week
  , id
  , MyDate

  from table_1
  ) a

where a.MyDate between sysdate - cast(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') as int) - 28 + 1 and sysdate - cast(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') as int)

group by Week
```